# Is this sentence correct? "A lot of sugar have been added to the milk."

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Is this sentence correct? "A lot of sugar have been added to the milk."
Please explain it.

Comment: Was it...  White sugar, brown sugar, cane sugar, and fruit sugar?  Even so, would need an s

Comment: @Menasheh Totally irrelevant. The word sugar" is being used as a non-count noun in this example. It's referring to the product as a whole, not individual kinds of sugar.

Comment: @BillJ that's an opinion.  We don't have much context.

Comment: @Menasheh It's not opinion, it's fact. As written, "sugar" is clearly being used in a non-count way. We cannot second-guess the author of the sentence and assume that they might have made a mistake and meant to write plural "sugars". It is written as singular "sugar" and we have to assume that's what they meant. Simple  really!

Comment: Is this just a homework assignment?…

Comment: @BillJ: You _can_ assume the author has made a mistake, because the sentence given is ungrammatical.  The point Menasheh is getting at is that _"A lot of sugars (of various types) have been added to the milk"_ would be grammatical.  However, that'd be a strange situation, so you're right that _"a lot of sugar has been..."_ is likely what they intended.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> *A lot of sugar have/has been added to the milk.*

No, the verb should be the singular "has".

The quantificational noun "lot" is number-transparent, which means that the whole noun phrase takes on the number of the noun that is complement of the preposition "of", which in this case is the non-count "sugar".

Since non-count nouns like "sugar" take singular verb agreement it follows that the verb must be the singular "has".

Comment: Non-count nouns are also known as [uncountable or mass nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun).

Comment: Say the recipe called for confectioners sugar, brown sugar, granulated sugar, invert sugar and 10 other types of sugar.  The sentence could be correct as "A lot of **sugars have** been added to the milk".  I consider your answer correct, but wanted to point out that there is a case where "have" would be correct and "sugar" would need to be changed to "sugars".

Comment: I added sucrose, dextrose and maltose to my milk. Lots of sugars have been added to my milk.

Comment: Here in the UK, we sometimes use the plural in a count noun sense to refer to spoonfuls, e.g. "How many sugars would you like in your tea?"

Comment: @BobbyJack - note that in that usage it's _sugars_, though. I'd also judge it an informal usage, perhaps because to my Canadian understanding, a double-double is two milk and two sugar (rather than two milks and two sugars), with "servings of" implied.

Comment: In this part of the US people definitely say "two sugars", but in the original context nobody would ever say "a lot of sugars" unless it was a very specific context - someone at a fast food restaurant, say, grabbing a handful of 20 sugar packets.

Comment: *How many sugars...?* is merely a shortened version of *How many spoons of sugar...?*, so it's not strictly related to the OP's question, although it's a valid observation for English-language learners to be aware of (both in this case, and as a general warning).

Answer (score 22):

No, **sugar** is an [uncountable noun](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-countable-un.htm), and **A lot** does not quantify it, so it takes **has**: A lot of sugar **has** been added to the milk.

However, if you quantify it, you may say: **Two cups of** sugar **have** been added to the milk.

Comment: Lots are countable.  In this case, a single lot was specified.

Comment: @Physics-Compute In this context, "a lot" is the idiom meaning "a large but nonspecific quantity", *not* the auctioneering jargon meaning "a discrete item or set of items that will be auctioned as a unit".

Comment: @Physics-Compute so I can say "please add two lots of sugar to my coffee"?

Comment: It's not an idiom.  Its use is as a metaphor.  A lot that is full of something usually indicates there are many somethings involved in order to fill the lot. Another expression that is less metaphorical, but is a single big container that holds many smaller items is "a basket (full) of oranges."  Above, we have a lot (full) of sugar, which obviously can't normally fit into a suggested glass of milk, so we are meant to envision a (single) lot full of sugar being put into the glass as a metaphor for how much sugar is actually in there.  A single lot is countable and singular.

Comment: @Andrew You can say it, yes, but one lot is usually enough to get the point across that you want to be diabetic.

Comment: Though, you can say "Please add *lots* of sugar..." to mean that you want a large amount of sugar. That use is idiomatic, and is usually only used in speaking, not writing.

Comment: Isn't the point more so that the subject of the sentence is `A lot`, and the verb should match the subject. That sugar is uncountable is irrelevant.

Comment: @Pysics-Compute The "lot" in the example is **not** countable - it's a quantificational non-count noun. It is head of the NP, but it's the noun that is complement of the preposition "of" that determines the number of the whole NP, in this case "sugar" which is being used in a non-count way. You are confusing this "lot" with the "lot" found in examples like "We have two lots of people coming today", where "lot" is a count noun.

Comment: @Kenneth K No! It's totally relevant, indeed key to understanding the grammar. The "lot" under consideration is number-transparent, meaning  that for verb agreement purposes the whole NP takes on the number of the noun that is complement to the prep "of", which in this case is the non-count "sugar". If the complement noun were plural like, say, "flavourings", then the whole NP would become plural: "A lot of flavourings **were** added to the milk". Do you see the difference?

Comment: @BillJ What happens here, then:  `Several packets of sugar were placed before me. A lot ____ added to my coffee.` Is it now "was" or "were"? These sentences are nonsensical (I doubt you'd hear someone speak this way), but based on your logic I have to look at the 1st sentence to determine the 2nd sentence's verb form. That doesn't seem proper. I've only understood pronouns to be dependent on context found in previous sentences, not verbs.

Comment: That is, unless you're telling me that "a lot" functions as a pronoun in the 2nd sentence. If that be the case, then I concede, but I've never understood "a lot" to be a pronoun.

Comment: Hmmmm... Well it seems [according to Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lot) that "a lot" is treated like a pronoun. So I guess that means I concede  :)

Comment: @Kenneth K I've explained as clearly as I can that the "lot" under discussion here is a non-count quantificational noun. Please read my answer for a very simple explanation of how it works.

Comment: More evidence for the uncountability of "a lot": If we replaced it with "lots", the sentence would still only be grammatical with "has". "Lots of sugar have been added..." still doesn't work.

Comment: The plural form "lots" works in the same way as singular "lot": Lots of _sugar has_ been added" ~ "Lots of _things have_ been added.

Comment: @BillJ I Disagree.  A lot is used here as a measuring device.  It is correct to say, "One liter of sure has been added," and "Two liters of sugar have been added."  Apply that to a lot.

Comment: @Physics-Compute The crucial difference is that the non-count quantificational noun "lot" is **number-transparent**.  The count noun "liter is not number-transparent; unlike "lot",  it determines the number of the NP in the usual way. Please try to understand this.

Comment: @BillJ Please try to understand what a lot is literally.

Comment: @Physics-Compute I understand perfectly, thank you. I have explained this very carefully to you. I'm sorry if you cannot grasp this simple point of grammar. And I also carefully explained the difference between the nouns "liter" and "lot".

Comment: It seems to me that the difference here is that I am interpreting the word lot literally, and you are interpreting it as the popular, nonliteral meaning, disconnected from a physical lot.  Though noncount is the popular thought, the literal (countable) meaning of lot is necessary to understand the metaphor.

Comment: There are more than one use for the word; this does not mean that uses other than your suggested one are not also literal - in fact, they are.

Answer (score 3):

Although I think that [BillJ's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/119457/10238) is probably a correct way to look at this issue, it seems a little technical. It's possible to look at this sentence another way and understand it with fairly basic, high-school level grammar.

The subject of this sentence is "a lot", which is singular. Therefore, the verb should be "has".

> A lot has been added to my milk.

"Of sugar" is an adjectival prepositional phrase, modifying "a lot". It's telling you what *kind* of lot has been added.

Using 'lot' in this sense is somewhat idiomatic, in that a 'lot' is

> an article or set of articles for sale at an auction. ([MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lot))

Although it's become so common to use it in this fashion that the idiomatic usage is probably more common than the original one. It has this definition:

> a considerable quantity or extent   (MW)

So,

> A considerable quantity has been added to my milk.

What kind of considerable quantity?

> A considerable quantity *of sugar*.

Regardless of how you look at it, you should use "has". It's an informal usage anyway, so the exact technical details aren't that important.

Comment: This sounds reasonable to me until I consider examples like "a lot of people" or "a lot of cups", at which point it seems wrong. "Lot" taken as a noun should still be singular, but the whole phrase acts as plural, so something else is going on here, right?

Comment: @DanGetz From my memory of grammar in primary school, that is a common error in English. It doesn't matter if the phrase sounds like it is plural, what matters are the rules of grammar. The rules of grammar identify subject/verb agreement, not subject-phrase/verb agreement. A lot is one singular thing (hence the "a"). A lot of people is still just one lot.

Comment: @KennethK. do you (or does someone else) have a source for "a lot of" working this way in English, when one is *not* speaking of actual lots? Because that just doesn't match my experience.

Comment: For example, "a number" is *also* singular, but "a number of people"…

Comment: @Dan Getz The point is that "sugar" in the OP's example is being used as a non-count noun. The same would apply to "A lot of people are ...". Of course, if it was a count noun like "cups", it would be a plural NP: "A lot of cups are ..."

Comment: @Shule The "lot" that we're considering is a number-transparent non-count noun and nothing at all like "box". Singular "lot" takes "a" as determiner, and is used a great many speakers. It's not used as an adjective; it's head of the NP and since it's number transparent, the whole NP takes on the number of the noun that is complement to the preposition "of". Grammatically, "box" is quite different since it is not number-transparent and hence  determines the number of the NP: "A box of material/toys has just arrived". (singular verb in both cases)

Comment: @BillJ I agree with you; what I'm questioning is this answer and Kenneth's comments which seem to me to be saying otherwise.

Comment: @DanGetz I think there are multiple ways to look at this that are equally valid. The main point is that they should use "has". I upvoted BillJ's answer as well, just wanted to add another interpretation.

Comment: @DCShannon so in your interpretation, what happens in "a lot of people"? Is "a lot" still singular? Is the verb still "has"? If not, then this answer seems to me more likely to confuse than to help.

Comment: I don't think the "auction" definition of "lot" is the original one. The M-W link you give suggests the origin is OE "hlot", which basically means "portion".

Comment: @psmears Perhaps "original" is the wrong word. It was my understanding that that usage preceded the current "lots" usage, so maybe "previous" or "older".

Comment: @DCShannon: I think the (much) older meaning of "portion" is the origin of both the auction meaning and the "lots of" one - i.e. they're indirectly related, but the auction meaning isn't a direct ancestor of the "lots of" one.

Comment: @DCShannon Maybe the concept of "[measure words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_word)" is useful here?  One _quart_ of milk, fifty _head_ of cattle, a _lot_ of sugar: feels like the same construction to me.

Comment: Rather than "a lot of people" you might say "many people", without changing the meaning (subject is plural, use 'have'). You are unlikely to say "many sugar" in this context, you would say "much sugar": use 'has'. Now, if several types of sugar are used then you might use "many sugars", but it doesn't seem likely in this case.

Comment: Just replace "a lot of" with "a box of" or "a group of".

Answer (score 1):

You could use "have" with the countable word "sugars" or similarly "sugar crystals". In the context of tea or coffee, you may ask for 3 sugars, where it is implied you are talking about specific units of quantity like cubes or packets.